# Creating a hyperlink to display a PDF stored in SQL Server

Tags: image, sql-server-2012

What I have is an off the shelf product that allows some minimal customization.  I am trying to create a sql script to display a pdf that is stored in the database as an image.

In the example below I am trying to create a grid view to various documents and such for the user to review.  All of it works with the exception of the attachment field.  It is a image field that only displays the binary data.  I would like to have it display a link and have it open up in adobe when you click on it.
I am running SQL server 2012

```
select nm.id_num,nm.first_name, nm.last_name, 
 '<a    href="https://myvista.rvu.edu/ICS/Portlets/CUS/ICS/
Jenzabar.ContainedForm/Views/  ReportWindow.aspx?SubmissionID=' 
+ convert(nvarchar(36), SubmissionID) + '">supplemental app</a>'
 as  [Supplemental app],
attachment
from name_master nm 
  join [ICS_NET].[dbo].[fwk_user] fu on fu.hostid=nm.id_num
  join [ICS_NET].[dbo].[CF_Submissions]  s on s.userid=fu.id
  join attachments a on a.id_num=nm.id_num
where nm.id_num=@@HostID
```

Answer (score 0):

I can share an example of what I have done in the past ...

First, create the http link field with something like this ... ignore the case statement if you do not need to have a different link for different environments.

```
   ,case
        when @@SERVERNAME like '%CF-PROD%' then 'http://cf-prod-crm01:5559/crm.ashx?id=' + CAST(c.OpportunityID as varchar(36))
        when @@SERVERNAME like '%CF-STG%' then 'http://cf-stg-crm01:5559/crm.ashx?id=' + CAST(c.OpportunityID as varchar(36))
        when @@SERVERNAME like '%CF-QA%' then 'http://cf-qa-crm01:5559/crm.ashx?id=' + CAST(c.OpportunityID as varchar(36))
        when @@SERVERNAME like '%CF-DEV%' then 'http://cf-dev-crm01:5559/crm.ashx?id=' + CAST(c.OpportunityID as varchar(36))
        END AS 'CRMOpportunityLink'
```

To test, this link should work if you were to copy it and put it manually into a browser for your specific app.

In a report, such as SSRS, you can create a hyperlink using the Action area in TextBox, select "Go to URL" and insert the following in the expression:

```
"javascript:void(window.open('" + Fields!CRMOpportunityLink.Value + "','_blank'))")
```